# Screen Images overlapping Dialog in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, dialog

I am trying to create a game in LibGDX, in the game i have created Dialog which will appear when we press Back Pressed key, However when Dialog Box got appears images from Display Screen are overlapping the Dialog due to which my contents got hidden.
[image]

Following are my code

```
public class GamePlayScreen extends AbstractScreen {
private String TAG = "Game Play Screen";
private SpriteBatch batch;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private Stage stage;
private int width = 0;
private int height = 0;
private GameDrawer gameDrawer;
private AbstractGameController gameController;


public GamePlayScreen(Assests assests) {
    this.assests = assests;
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, width, height);
    camera.update();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    FillViewport viewport = new FillViewport(width, height, camera);
    viewport.update(width, height, true);
    stage = new Stage(viewport);
    gameDrawer = new GameDrawer(batch, assests);
    gameController = new GameController(camera, assests);
    Gdx.input.setCatchKey(Input.Keys.BACK, true);

}

public void show() {
    //    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Enters show method");
    Image backgroundImage = new Image(assests.manager.get(Assests.backgroundImageTexture));
    backgroundImage.setSize(width, height);
    stage.addActor(backgroundImage);
    InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    multiplexer.addProcessor(stage);
    multiplexer.addProcessor(new GestureDetector(new TouchController(gameController)));
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);


    //   Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Executed show method succussfully");
}

public void render(float delta) {
    //Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Enters render method");
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.187f, 0.246f, 0.621f, 1.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(16384);
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.BACK))
        onBackPressed();
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();

    batch.begin();
    gameController.processGameRender();

    gameDrawer.drawDealtDeck(gameController.getDealtDeck());
    gameDrawer.drawDiscardedDeck(gameController.getDiscardedDeck());

    gameDrawer.drawPlayerDeck(gameController);

    batch.end();

    //   Gdx.app.log(TAG, "render metod executed succussfully");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, "Back Key Pressed");
    Skin skin = assests.manager.get(Assests.glassySkin);
    Button btnQuit = new TextButton("Quit", skin);
    Button btnRestart = new TextButton("Restart", skin);
    Button btnCancel = new TextButton("Cancel", skin);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Are you sure you want to exit", skin) {
        @Override
        protected void result(Object object) {
            super.result(object);
        }
    };
    dialog.button(btnQuit);
    dialog.button(btnCancel);
    dialog.button(btnRestart);
    dialog.show(stage);
    dialog.padLeft(50.0f);
    dialog.padRight(50.0f);
    dialog.padBottom(10.0f);
    dialog.show(this.stage);

     /*  Dialog dialog= new Dialog("Are you sure want to Exit",skin){
        @Override
        public float getPrefWidth() {
            return width/2;
        }
        @Override
        public float getPrefHeight() {
           return height/2;
        }
    };
    dialog.setModal(false);
    dialog.setMovable(false);
    dialog.setResizable(false);
    dialog.setFillParent(false);
    btnQuit.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            Gdx.app.log(TAG,"Quit Button Pressed");
        return true;
        }
    });
    float btnsize=40.0f;
    Table table=new Table();
    table.add(btnQuit).width(btnsize).height(btnsize);
    table.add(btnRestart).width(btnsize).height(btnsize);
    table.add(btnCancel).width(btnsize).height(btnsize);
    dialog.getButtonTable().add(table).center();
    dialog.show(stage).setPosition(width/4,height/4);
    stage.addActor(dialog);
    */


}
```

}

Any suggestion, regarding how i can stop images overlapping will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the dialog to be drawn over your game, then you must draw your game before you draw your Stage in the `render` method.

If you have other stage objects that must be drawn behind some of your game objects, you will need two stages.